# Inverse search in AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get all instances that are not attached to an autoscaling group. All instances from an autoscaling group have a tag **aws:autoscaling:groupName**. I can get those instances with this:

```
reservations = ec.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        # Instances in autoscaling group
        {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['aws:autoscaling:groupName']},
        # Instances should be in running mode
        {'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}
    ]
).get(
    'Reservations', []
)

instances = sum(
[
    [i for i in r['Instances']]
    for r in reservations
], [])

print "Number of the instances in autoscaling: %d" % len(instances)
```

But what I really need to get are instances that are not in autoscaling. As there is an [inverse search](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html#advancedsearch) in AWS Console, I'm hoping there is in Python as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code can do it for you. There is no direct inverse search option in boto till date. Hope someday, someone will add that option :)

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/173

```
reservations = ec.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        # Instances should be in running mode
        {'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}
    ]
)

Count=0
for Instances in reservations['Reservations']:
    for Instance in Instances['Instances']:
        if "aws:autoscaling:groupName" not in str(Instance):
            # your logic on servers without AutoScaling Group goes here
            Count=Count+1

print "Number of the instances Without autoscaling: ", Count
```

Comment: By "`# your logic on servers without AutoScaling Group goes here`" you mean what I'll do with the instances not in AS group? (e.g. creating snapshots of their volumes) Just making sure.

Comment: Exactly. If you are trying automate the snapshot, you may check my git hub project. (https://github.com/bijohnvincent/ScheduleBackupLambda). This project is for scheduling AMI and snapshot based on tags. You may 'watch' the project as I will be adding more options when I get time.